# Apply image smoothing and edge detection algorithms on a 2.4 GB GeoTIFF image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, edge-detection, geotiff

So I have over 150,000 huge GeoTIFF images (each 2.4 GB) which I need to run image smoothing and edge detection (LoG Filter) on, to get a sharpened image. I read the image using Gdal, smoothed it, subsampled it, created a high-pass filter (level 5) and reconstructed the image.

This works fine for a normal .jpg file.

But I'm not able to accomplish this for a huge TIFF file becaus I keep running into memory errors even with a 32 GB RAM 8 core processor and 4 TB disk space.

What is the best way to do heavy weight image processing / image segmentation on a Python 3.6 Ubuntu 18 LTS?

Comment: Try [dask](http://dask.pydata.org) in case you are using numpy or numpy based libraries (e.g. scikit-image) to process your images.

Answer (score 2):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) can process huge images [quickly and in little memory](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use). It's LGPL, runs on Linux, macOS and Windows, and works on every version of Python. Most linuxes (including Ubuntu) have it in the package manager.

It's a demand-driven, streaming image processing library. Instead of processing images in single huge lumps, it constructs a network of image processing operators behind your back and pixels are pulled through your computer's memory in small regions by the need to create the output.

For example, I can run this program:

```
import sys
import pyvips

# access='sequential' puts pyvips into streaming mode for this image
im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')
im = im.crop(100, 100, im.width - 200, im.height - 200)
# 10% shrink, lanczos3 (by default)
im = im.resize(0.9)
mask = pyvips.Image.new_from_array([[-1, -1,  -1], 
                                    [-1,  16, -1], 
                                    [-1, -1,  -1]], scale=8)
# integer convolution ... you can use large float masks too, canny,
# sobel, etc. etc.
im = im.conv(mask, precision='integer')
im.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

On a 40k x 30k pixel GeoTIFF image:

```
$ vipsheader SAV_X5S_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif 
SAV_X5S_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif: 42106x29852 uchar, 4 bands, srgb, tiffload
```

On this 2015 laptop runs like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e python3 bench.py SAV_X5S_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif x.tif
257012:101.43
```

ie. 260mb of ram, 101s of elapsed time. It should be quite a bit quicker on your large machine.

One issue you might have is with the GeoTIFF tags: they won't be preserved by pyvips. Perhaps you won't need them in later processing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such large images are processed tile-wise. The idea is to divide the image up into tiles, read each one in independently, with enough "overlap" to account for the filtering applied, process it and write it to file.

The TIFF standard knows the "tiled" format (I believe GeoTIFF files are typically stored in a tiled format). This format is explicitly designed to make it easy to read in a small window of the image without having to piece together bits and pieces from all over the file. Each tile in the TIFF file can be indexed by location, and is encoded and compressed independently, making it easy to read in and write out one tile at a time.

The overlap you need depends on the filtering applied. If you apply, say, a Laplace of Gaussian filter with a 9x9 window (reaches 4 pixels past the central pixel), and then overlap needs to be only 4 pixels. If you chain filters, you typically want to add the reach of each filter to obtain a total overlap value.

Next, divide the image into some multiple of the tile size in the TIFF file. Say the file has tiles of 512x512 pixels. You can choose to process 8 tiles at once, a region of 2048x2048 pixels.

Now loop over the image in steps of 2048 in each dimension. Read in the 8 tiles, and include neighboring tiles, which you will crop so that you get square images of 2048+2*4 pixels to a side. Process the sub-image, remove the overlap region, and write the rest to the corresponding tiles in the output TIFF file. The output TIFF file should be set up in the same way as the input TIFF file.

I am sure there is software out there that automates this process, but I don't know of any in Python. If you implement this yourself, you will need to learn how to read and write individual tiles in the TIFF file. One option is [pylibtiff](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff).

Comment: pyvips works pretty much like this, and automatically vectorises (it has a run-time code generator) and threads (it'll load all of your cores by default) too. I had a go at an answer.